# How to generate a JWT from Angular client?

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, angular2-services, auth0

I've been searching for a while an official way to create a JWT from an Angular client. Some posts recommend not to do that because of security
issues, even the `auth0/jwt-angular2` doesn't have the function to generate it.

Comment: It makes no sense. Why would not you explain the original problem you're solving?

Comment: That's the problem, I couldn't find an official way to generate a JWT from angular 2.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a solution. Generating a JWT on the client side makes no sense. Why do you need it?

Comment: For server authentication. I need to send some POST and GET signed with it.

Comment: You cannot authenticate on the client. It makes no sense to sign anything in the client - since client runs on the client.

Comment: I get it. I think you're right. I guess that's why there's no official way to do it, well, at least with auth0/jwt-angular2.

Comment: Generating a JWT on the client has several applications, not the least of which is testing with a mock back-end or in unit tests.  You can leave your code unchanged and supply a valid JWT to your service layer .

Answer (score 1):

The JWT must be created at the server side once the user is registered/logged in.

After that, in a server response the token is sent back to the browser. And finally you have to store this token in the browser local storage for subsequent requests.

Remember to use HTTPS otherwise anyone can capture the tokens easily with WireShark.

Comment: "you have to develop your expiry token algorithm" --- you don't, just let JWTs expire themselves. "otherwise anyone" --- certainly not "anyone".

Comment: Add an expiry date to your user userExpiryToken: { type: Date, required: false },. Then for every request check if the token is expired. If it is expired

Comment: jwtSimple.encode(user, jwtConfig.secret); Creates the token. If you change anything in the user, like emptying expiry token date, or setting a boolean flag to expired, it will change our token, therefore the user won't be able to use the token again. It's a simple way to force the user to renew the token or to make him or her to login in again, or to request a new token through a service. Have a look to this page: https://jwt.io . It shows how the token is built.

Comment: `exp` claim is the part of the standard (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4), you don't need to add any other extra check. Your advice with "If you change anything in the user, like emptying expiry token date, or setting a boolean flag to expired" makes no sense: if you persist your tokens on the server side - you don't need JWT http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: Indeed, zerkms. My suggestion is based on JWT.

Comment: Then please remove "The downside I found about JWT is that you have to develop your expiry token algorithm", since you don't need to develop anything: every compliant client has it by default.

Comment: Here you have another posts talking about the expiry token algorithm: https://auth0.com/forum/t/reading-expiry-date-of-jwt-on-client/2033/2

Comment: You don't need to read forum posts, it's a part of the standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4

Comment: Well, hope we help to our colleague.

Comment: Yeah, no, it need not be created on the server so to say it "must" demonstrates some sort of magical thinking.  You can generate it anywhere.  When it makes practical sense is another question. On the client, the main use-case is testing.